# JavaFX Parallelogram CSS

Tags: javafx, javafx-css

How to create a parallelogram button with JavaFX CSS?

Ex: [Parallelogram](https://coveloping.com/app/themes/codebase/page-templates/css-shapes-generator/images/parallelogram-right.png)

Comment: Do you need to create it with just CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `-fx-shape` property:

```
-fx-shape: "M50 100 L150 100 L180 250 L80 250 Z";
```

Comment: Thanks man, it works. How is the best/easy way to create this svg path?

Comment: I think there should be some online SVG editors, try to google them. Cheers!